# How to check if a tensor transform a tensor?

Tags: tensor-calculus, covariance

Suppose $A^{\mu_1 \cdots \mu_n}_{\nu_{n+1}\cdots \nu_m}$ is a tensor. That means it transforms a tensor. How do I show that it transforms as a tensor? How do I see that $\cos (A^{\mu_1 \cdots \mu_n}_{\nu_{n+1}\cdots \nu_m})$ or some other non-tensor does not transform like a tensor?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what definition of tensor you're using? Otherwise, your question just seems to be "is a tensor a tensor, and is a non-tensor not a tensor".

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32011/2451. Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/317502/2451

Comment: @knzjou I come from a maths background, and i think the way stuff is defined seems to change as tutors sees necessary. They say a tensor is a tensor if it transforms as a tensor. This all tutors seems to agree on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A tensor (or more appropriately tensor field) $T^{i_1 \dots i_m}_{j_1 \dots j_n}$ of rank $(m,n)$ transforms as,

$$T'^{i'_1 \dots i'_m}_{j'_1 \dots j'_m} = \left( \frac{\partial\tilde{x}^{i'_1}}{\partial x^{i_1}} \dots \frac{\partial\tilde{x}^{i'_m}}{\partial x^{i_m}} \right) \left(\frac{\partial x^{j_1}}{\partial \tilde{x}^{j'_1}}\dots \frac{\partial x^{j_m}}{\partial \tilde{x}^{j'_m}} \right)T^{i_1 \dots i_m}_{j_1 \dots j_n} $$

under a coordinate transformation $x \to \tilde{x}$. Now, if we have some multi-dimensional array, we need to know specifically what it is to be able to check if it is a tensor. Without further details, the best we can say is it transforms as a tensor if it satisfies the above definition.

---

As an example, consider the Christoffel symbols,

$$\Gamma^i_{kl} = \frac12 g^{im} \left( \partial_l g_{mk} + \partial_k g_{ml} - \partial_m g_{kl} \right).$$

We know that the metric $g$ is a tensor and thus we know exactly how it transforms under a coordinate transformation. Thus, to figure out if the Christoffel symbols are tensors, we need only plug this in and compute. But we find that,

$$\Gamma'^{k}_{ij} = \frac{\partial x'^p}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial x'^q}{\partial x^j} \Gamma^r_{pq} \frac{\partial x^k}{\partial x'^r} + \frac{\partial x^k}{\partial x'^m} \frac{\partial^2 x'^m}{\partial x^i \partial x^j}$$

and thus clearly does *not* transform in the manner defined for a tensor, which is why we call them the Christoffel *symbols*. As you can see, we need to know what the quantity in question is to be able to check if it transforms the right way.